# How to Add Sequential Numbers to Layer Names using ezdxf

Tags: python-3.x, autocad, dxf

I want to know how to use ezdxf to add sequential numbers to layer names.

AutoCAD layer name list:

- ABC
- DEF
- GHI

Layer name list after change:

- AAA1
- AAA2
- AAA3

I want to change the layer name as above.

I tried using a `for` statement, but it doesn't work.

```py
import ezdxf
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import os
import re
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, TextIO, Iterable

file_list=glob.glob('./input/*.dxf')
for filename in file_list:
    dwg = ezdxf.readfile(filename,encoding='auto',legacy_mode=False)
    msp = dwg.modelspace()

    old_layername1 = '\w+'
    for layer in dwg.layers:
        s=layer.dxf.name
        old_layername11 = re.search(old_layername1,s)
        if old_layername11:
            old_layername11=old_layername11.group()

            for i in range(1,10):
                new_layername1 = 'AAA'+str(i)

            try:
                layer = dwg.layers.get(old_layername11)
            except ValueError:
                print('Layer {} not found.'.format(old_layername11))
            else:
                layer.dxf.name = new_layername1
```

The numbers after all layer names become the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate `for` loop to increment the variable `i`; instead, increment this variable as you iterate over the layer collection.

i.e.:

```
i = 1
for layer in dwg.layers:
    new_layername1 = 'AAA' + str(i)
    ...
    i += 1
```

You may also want to check whether the target layer name exists prior to renaming.